# If there is no P tag within my DIV then remove min-height on div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically, I have a simple div with a h2 and p tag contained within the div and I was wondering if there was a way I could possibly remove the styling on the div if the P did not exist?

markup and styling below.

```
<style>
.hotel-header { min-height: 100px; }
</style>

<div class="hotel-header">
<h2>Hotel Name</h2>
<p>Hotel address</p>
</div>
```

any help or tips would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If only CSS would support the [`:has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo-class...

Comment: <html>
<header>
<style>
 .hotel-header { min-height: 100px;}
</style>
</header>
<body onload="init()">

<div class="hotel-header ">
<h2>Hotel Name</h2>
<p>Hotel address</p>
</div>

<script>
function init(){
 var divItem = document.getElementsByClassName('hotel-header')[0];    
 if(divItem.getElementsByTagName('P').length == 0){
     divItem.classList.remove('hotel-header');
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: @RaviRajindu removing the class is not an option - h2 class has padding top and bottom and this then causes alignment issues

Comment: if(divItem.getElementsByTagName('P').length == 0){
     divItem.style.minHeight = '0px';
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with:

```
const headers = document.getElementsByClassName('hotel-header');
for (let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
  if (headers.item(i).getElementsByTagName('p').length === 0) {
    headers.item(i).classList.remove('hotel-header');
  }
}
```

Comment: `if (headers.item(i).getElementsByTagName('p').length > 0)` is correct condition

Comment: @user1531038 _remove the styling on the div *if the P did not exist*_

Comment: oh yeah.. I mis-read it!

Comment: @hsz Removing the class is not an option - as the H2 has padding top and bottom and this then causes alignment issues - any other suggestions? thank you